# finding the second partial derivative of a function that depends on y and a function of y

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am interested in finding the second partial derivative of a function that depends on $y$ and a function of $y$
$$\frac{\partial^2f(x(y), y)}{\partial x \ \partial y}$$

My approach (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027839/partial-derivative-of-a-two-variables-function-one-of-which-dependent-on-the-ot?noredirect=1&lq=1)) is to solve this directly using the chain rule for partial derivatives, resulting in
$$\require{cancel} \frac{\partial}{\partial x }(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \xcancel{\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x }(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}$$

However this seems to be incorrect as it just results in the original expression plus some potentially non zero term.

My question is how to calculate second order partial derivatives w.r.t. y and a function of y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $g : y \mapsto f(x(y),y)$ is only having one independent variable. Namely $y$. Hence  $$\frac{\partial^2f(x(y), y)}{\partial x \ \partial y}$$ doesn't have any meaning.